# Check whether File is a public key file in Java Java FX

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, fxml

```
FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
 fileChooser.setTitle("Open Resource File");
 fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
         new ExtensionFilter("Key files", "*.pem"),
         );
```

The code is in the Java FX Controller. And my code uses a FXML file, where this code is executed upon clicking a button.

1. I am trying to accept only public key files from the Java FX input. Is this code snippet correct? 
   Is the extension filter right?
2. How can I check whether the file entered is a public key file? Is there a way to check or some tool?
3. How can I avoid InvalidKeySpecException?

Comment: Your code filters filenames based on the `pem` file extension. -- Do you have some file validation in your code ? Why do not try sign a dummy message and check the Exception to detect if the key is invalid ?

Comment: Can you make a suggestion on how to do that? With a try catch statement? If so, how